# Multiple files for cameraview while build app for android react native

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-camera, react-native-unimodules, expo-camera

I am using `react-native-camera` and `expo-camera` in my project. Along with this I am using few firebase features as well.

App is working fine for iOS but not for Android.

After removing firebase classes, I am able to run the app properly in simulator. While creating apk, I am getting following error.

I have to exclude this group from react-native-camera, but I have used latest react-native version. So, it is using auto linking and it's not implemented in build.gradle.

build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        supportLibVersion = "29.0.0"
        playServicesVersion = "17.0.0" // or find latest version
        androidMapsUtilsVersion = "1.2.1"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0')

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

        // Check that you have the Google Services Gradle plugin v4.3.2 or later
        // (if not, add it).
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

        // Add the Crashlytics Gradle plugin.
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.1.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        maven {
            // expo-camera bundles a custom com.google.android:cameraview
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/expo-camera/android/maven"
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }

    }
}
```

android/app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply from: '../../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/gradle.groovy'

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // Google Services Gradle plugin

// Apply the Crashlytics Gradle plugin
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

apply from: project(':react-native-config').projectDir.getPath() + "/dotenv.gradle"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation. If none specified and
 *   // "index.android.js" exists, it will be used. Otherwise "index.js" is
 *   // default. Can be overridden with ENTRY_FILE environment variable.
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
 *   bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and mirrored here.  If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

project.ext.vectoricons = [
        iconFontNames: [ 'MaterialIcons.ttf', 'MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf' ] // Name of the font files you want to copy
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"


android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rnboilerplate"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.7.1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'

    }

    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            storeFile file('rnapp-upload-key.keystore')
            storePassword 'RNappkey'
            keyAlias 'rnapp-key-alias'
            keyPassword 'RNappkey'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst "lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so"
        pickFirst "lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so"
        pickFirst "lib/x86/libc++_shared.so"
        pickFirst "lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so"
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version"

    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation project(':react-native-config')
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"
    implementation project(':react-native-community-netinfo')

    addUnimodulesDependencies()

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
      exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
    // Recommended: Add the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.3'

    // Add the Firebase Crashlytics SDK.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.1'

    // Add the Firebase SDK for Dynamic Links.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:19.1.0'



}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

Error:

```
Type com.google.android.cameraview.AspectRatio$1 is defined multiple times: /Users/smritiibm/Desktop/Projects/ReactNativeAccelerators/reactnativedemo/node_modules/react-native-camera/android/build/.transforms/5ebdf9d41dc40332f9b99f153eb9b6a7/classes/classes.dex, /Users/smritiibm/Desktop/Projects/ReactNativeAccelerators/reactnativedemo/android/app/build/intermediates/external_libs_dex/release/mergeExtDexRelease/classes.dex

com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete

com.android.tools.r8.utils.b: Error: /Users/smritiibm/Desktop/Projects/ReactNativeAccelerators/reactnativedemo/node_modules/react-native-camera/android/build/.transforms/5ebdf9d41dc40332f9b99f153eb9b6a7/classes/classes.dex, Type com.google.android.cameraview.AspectRatio$1 is defined multiple times: /Users/smritiibm/Desktop/Projects/ReactNativeAccelerators/reactnativedemo/node_modules/react-native-camera/android/build/.transforms/5ebdf9d41dc40332f9b99f153eb9b6a7/classes/classes.dex, /Users/smritiibm/Desktop/Projects/ReactNativeAccelerators/reactnativedemo/android/app/build/intermediates/external_libs_dex/release/mergeExtDexRelease/classes.dex

Error: /Users/smritiibm/Desktop/Projects/ReactNativeAccelerators/reactnativedemo/node_modules/react-native-camera/android/build/.transforms/5ebdf9d41dc40332f9b99f153eb9b6a7/classes/classes.dex, Type com.google.android.cameraview.AspectRatio$1 is defined multiple times: /Users/smritiibm/Desktop/Projects/ReactNativeAccelerators/reactnativedemo/node_modules/react-native-camera/android/build/.transforms/5ebdf9d41dc40332f9b99f153eb9b6a7/classes/classes.dex, /Users/smritiibm/Desktop/Projects/ReactNativeAccelerators/reactnativedemo/android/app/build/intermediates/external_libs_dex/release/mergeExtDexRelease/classes.dex
```

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: we replaced react-native-camera with expo-camera. Now everything is working as expected.

Comment: can you share in which file did you replaced the package name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to replace `react-native-camera` with `expo-camera`. Now everything is working fine.

Answer (score -1):

Add these lines in `android/app/build.gradle` after Firebase dependencies:

```
implementation (project(':react-native-camera')) {
  exclude group: "com.google.android.cameraview"
}
```

Comment: please add output of command ‘./gradlew app:dependencies’